# Any way to print all nil objects in scope?

Tags: ruby, debugging, null

I frequently encounter erroneous `nil` values when running tests. In order to find the problem, I end up inserting a bunch of lines like:

```
puts 'variable x is nil' if x.nil?
puts 'variable y is nil' if y.nil?
...
```

Which slowly gets me closer to the problem.  Is there a gem or something that can quickly print a list of all `nil` variables in the current scope?  Or some method of debugging my methods that's a little less laborious?

Comment: Ahm, no. What's the kind of errors you get? Most probably you can make sense of them in a different way.

Comment: What's an "erroneous nil value"? It's not clear to me what problem you're actually trying to solve.

Comment: Sorry. Problems where something is nil and it shouldn't be - either I'm referencing the wrong thing, or requesting with wrong paramaters, or accidentally creating a new variable when I mean to reference an existing one.  All sorts of things~ analagous to 'null pointer errors'.

Comment: "Any way to print all nil objects in scope?" – There is only one `nil` object in Ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using so-called `printf`-debugging to track down these problems you're probably doing it wrong. You probably want to be writing tests that assert the presence of a value, then assert additional conditions:

```
assert x
assert y
```

It seems odd you're getting such a large number of `nil` values that you need to go out of your way to track them down. Generally they're produced at a particular point in time, so trap them as soon as possible to avoid having to check them later:

```
x = foo('a', 'b')
assert x, "foo(...) did not return a value"
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Typing 'assert y' is certainly easier.  I agree that it's unusual for this to be such a problem.  I think it's a combination of being new to Rails (and therefore forgetting the correct syntax for various gems / classes) and trying to write RSpec tests retrospectively.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing printf debugging, you may as well use `inspect` - that's what it's designed for:

```
puts 'variable x is #{x.inspect}'
puts 'variable y is #{y.inspect}'
```

There may be metaprogramming approaches to get all the local variables, but I think that'd be overkill.